# Check for new notifications on Firebase Cloud Messaging. (FCM)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am looking for a way of reading or listening to changes if at all am connected on firebase cloud messaging. Notifications are sent to the Android project on firebase, so am supposed to check on the Android application if there are new notifications.

Am I supposed to use the code below?

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom())
}
```

I tried to follow the documentation [Firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive). But am challenged by checking the new notifications on FCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can check whether the notification is fired or not** :

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() == null)
            return;
        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            handleNotification(remoteMessage, remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        }
```

Comment: @Idris for checking push is fired or not just check  remoteMessage.getNotification() != null.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to check if the notification is fired , that's what I wanted

Comment: Actaully I tried to log `remoteMessage.getNotification()`, after pushing a message on FCM, but it didn't log. but when I added the notification , it worked , what causes this ?

Comment: My other question will be, what if I first send the 1st message then afterwards I send the 2nd message, will this statement keep notifying `if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            handleNotification(remoteMessage, remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        }` that there's a change ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean like list all notifications from Android, you cannot do that I believe. It is the other way around: Firebase tells you when a new notification is available to one particular client via the onMessageReceived method. If you need additional logic you might want to use your backend to store notifications when fired and then the Android side could match the new notification based on it's unique ID with the backend to do further actions i.e. making sure the user got the notification, statistics etc.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I meant checking a new message each and every time its available in the cloud.